# Changing arrow of GTK+'s GtkComboBox?

Tags: gtk

How can I change the arrow image of GTK+'s GtkComboBox widget?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is change the `arrow-size` property to change the relative size of the arrows.

To go deeper than that, you probably need to look into theming.